# SqlDataSource Parameter Problem - Using loginName1 as sql parameter

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, parameters, sqldatasource, login-control

I am trying to retrieve database info that is specific to currently logged-in user.

The following 3 lines let me know that var1 is correct (As it displays it on the page)

```
Dim var1 As String<Br>
var1 = LoginName1.Page.User.Identity.Name<br>
Response.Write(var1)
```

But, when I try to use var1 as a parameter it is not working.... just wondered what I am missing.

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
        ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>" 
        SelectCommand="SELECT aspnet_Clubs.ClubName FROM aspnet_Clubs INNER JOIN aspnet_Users ON aspnet_Clubs.ClubID = aspnet_Users.ClubLinkID WHERE (aspnet_Users.UserName = @var1 )">
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
    <asp:DetailsView ID="DetailsView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateRows="False" 
        BackColor="LightGoldenrodYellow" BorderColor="Tan" BorderWidth="1px" 
        CellPadding="2" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" ForeColor="Black" 
        GridLines="None" Height="50px" Width="274px">
        <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="PaleGoldenrod" />
        <EditRowStyle BackColor="DarkSlateBlue" ForeColor="GhostWhite" />
        <Fields>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="ClubName" HeaderText="ClubName" 
                SortExpression="ClubName" />
        </Fields>
        <FooterStyle BackColor="Tan" />
        <HeaderStyle BackColor="Tan" Font-Bold="True" />
        <PagerStyle BackColor="PaleGoldenrod" ForeColor="DarkSlateBlue" 
            HorizontalAlign="Center" />
    </asp:DetailsView>
```

Answer (score 1):

You aren't setting the Select Parameter Value of your SqlDataSource.

[Here's an overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z72eefad.aspx) with code-samples of working with Parameters

Answer (score 0):

You need to define the parameter for `SqlDataSource` and then set it.

i.e.

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
        ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>" 
        SelectCommand="SELECT aspnet_Clubs.ClubName FROM aspnet_Clubs INNER JOIN aspnet_Users ON aspnet_Clubs.ClubID = aspnet_Users.ClubLinkID WHERE (aspnet_Users.UserName = @var1 )">

<SelectParameters>
<asp:Parameter Name="var1" Type="String" />
</SelectParameters>
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

and then in `Page_Load` or similar do:

`SqlDataSource1.SelectParameters("var1").DefaultValue = User.Identity.Name`

Comment: thanks,, my application is MVC3 so i cannot see any code behind files to add the Page_Load function.. is there any way to code it into the individual page(s)?

Comment: I don't use MVC and only have a vague knowlege of it but I guess you'd put it in the Controller's constructor/ation method? Then MVC would use it to construct the page?